# Logical AND as syntactic sugar for expression1 ? expression2 : false

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, conditional-operator, sicp

I'm reading "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs: JavaScript Edition" (2022) by Abelson, Sussman et al. On page 64, the book talks about the "logical composition operations" (logical AND, logical OR):

> - *expression1 && expression2*
>
> This operation expresses *logical conjunction*, meaning roughly the same as the English word *and*. This syntactic form is syntactic sugar for `expression1 ? expression2 : false`;
>
> - *expression1 || expression2*
>
> This operation expresses *logical disjunction*, meaning roughly the same as the English word *or*. This syntactic form is syntactic sugar for `expression1 ? true : expression2`.

I don't understand how `expression1 ? expression2 : false` could be the same thing as `expression1 && expression2`.

In the first case, we just evaluate whether expression1 is truthy.
In the second case, we evaluate whether both expression1 and expression2 are truthy.
So why are they the same thing? I hope you can enlighten me? :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: The text is wrong. You might say it's *similar* in order to illustrate what happens but it's most definitely not the same. Consder `0 && 1` is not the same result as `0 ? 1 : false`. The AND will produce `0` while the conditional statement will produce `false`.

Comment: You could say that `expression1 && expression2` is the same as `expression1 ? expression2 : expression1` which will be more correct but AND is not really syntactic sugar for it. The two are different `console.log("hello") ? "not reached" : console.log("hello")` is going to log *twice* while `console.log("hello") && "not reached"` would only log *once*.

Answer (score 0):

That's how the ternary (`?`) operator works, basically  `x = a ? b : c` translates to `x` is `b` if `a` is `true` and `c` otherwise.

In the case of `&&`, we fist check `expression1`, if it's `true`, the truthiness of the whole thing depends on `expression2` (which could be `true` or `false`), otherwise it's `false`